# AutoMultiplicationSymbol not displaying

Tags: display

Since $14.0$ I've had a minor but bizarre issue with the automatic multiplication symbol not appearing correctly. Previously, a space between numbers, for example, would instantly display a light gray multiplication symbol (by default it looks like $\times$). Now this symbol is only displayed by force. For example, I can change the setting in basic preferences with Appearance>Numbers>Multiplication>Use Symbol>Center Dot. After this, I can do the following:

```
In[8]:= ExpressionCell[HoldForm[2*3*5], 
 AutoMultiplicationSymbol -> {"Numbers"}]
```

and get output that looks like $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$. But for the life of me I can't get the center dot to display when typing input. I tried clearing all the settings and caches I could find, but nothing worked. I also checked that "ShowAutoStyles" is true in the options manager. Any tips would be appreciated. I'm also not very acquainted with this community so feel free to give suggestions or edit tags.

[image: Example]

Comment: I think you are misusing the AutoMultiplicationSymbol option, the setting should be a boolean. Perhaps `ExpressionCell[HoldForm[2 3 5], NumberMultiplier->"\[CenterDot]", AutoMultiplicationSymbol->True]` does what you want?

Comment: @CarlWoll I think that must have changed at some point? Looks like the default value for `AutoMultiplicationSymbol` is `{"Functions", "LineBreaks", "Numbers"}`. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place but thats in global options>formatting>expression formatting>display options

Comment: You're right, it did change in M13. Did you try resetting preferences to their defaults?